# Open Google Chrome from Command Line in predefined windows

Tags: google-chrome, command-line-arguments

From Windows Vista (within VBA, but thats probably irrelevant) I open web pages

```
Shell ("C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url " & URL)
```

I would like these pages to be opened in specific windows. I have come across the --new-window switch, but this always creates a new window. I would like an option to always go to a predefined window and only if it doesnt exist open a window for it.

E.g.

```
  ...Chrome.exe -window mywindowA -url URL1
  ...Chrome.exe -window mywindowB -url URL2
  ...Chrome.exe -window mywindowA -url URL3
```

should not affect any other open windows and instead open 2 new ones, one containing URL1 and URL3, the other URL2.

Comment: Rob - To clarify, we're assuming that mywindowA, B and C are *existing* Chrome windows?  Also, is "mywindowA" the window title, or what is it?

Comment: Second question first. Dont mind whether its a title or an internal handle as long as its something unique for each window. Regarding whether they exist, this should be flexible, i.e. if not then open a new one with that title/handle, otherwise add tabs to existing one of that name.

Comment: You could use `--user-data-dir` instead of `--new-window` switch. Then it should look like `...Chomre.exe --user-data-dir=[user-data-dir-1] -url URL1 ...Chomre.exe --user-data-dir=[user-data-dir-2] -url URL2 ...Chomre.exe --user-data-dir=[user-data-dir-1] -url URL3`

Comment: That seems to work. However, the pages live behind htaccess control and opening the new data dir loses the session. Is there a way of passing these on command line? Tried --login-password and --login-user, but rather than going straight to the pages I still see the login popup.